# Default page is shown despite changes / Frontend is not being updated

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

basically, i set up a project with meteor 1.7.0.3 a couple of days ago. The problem is: any changes to the files are not being shown when running the application on localhost. All I see is the default page.

[image: default page]

Things I tried out were:

- Re-building the meteor-project
- Restarting my PC
- Reinstalling dependencies
- Setting up a new meteor project
- Clearing my cache

The only change I made was to remove the letter "o" from "Meteor" in the main.html-file, by the way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Consider updating your question title to be a little more specific. People scrolling through the site can't gather enough from "Changes are not being shown." You'll lose half of your potential audience with a poorly formatted question title like this.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is not an IDE related issue (IDE not updating/saving your source files etc.)